# Как использовать поднятие экрана клавиатурой и при этом сделать statusBarColor прозрачным

Tags: java, android, layout

я использую

```
View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();

        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(
                View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
```

чтобы сделать statusBarColor прозрачным но при этом открытая клавиатура не поднимает экран и мне приходиться делать через костыли, я хочу чтобы клавиатура поднимала экран и statusBarColor был прозрачным подскажите как это сделать